# Winforms - can't resize when adding textbox

Tags: winforms, textbox, resize

I'm putting together a simple winforms app, which consists on 1 form and a textbox.
I want to have the textbox scale in width when the form is scaled by the user.

By default the textbox is a fixed width and anchored at the top & left. The form scales ok, but not the textbox.

If I apply left, top & right anchor to the textbox it only scales the textbox & form up and I can't shrink it.

Do I need to dynamically set the width of the textbox to that of the form?

Comment: What you have described is not usual behaviour, suggesting you have changed something. Have you tried this with a very simple example, one form with a textbox with left, top and right anchor set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to recreate this for 5 minutes and it resizes fine for me, and I've only been able to find one set of combinations that reproduces the behavior you describe:

Is the textbox inside a panel with **Autosize** set to "true" and **AutoSizeMode** set to "grow only" perhaps?  That's the only way I've been able to duplicate the behavior.

Here's a screenshot of the properties set this way.  My textbox is also set to anchor at top, left, right.  Again, this is the ONLY way I've been able to duplicate the behavior you're describing, so hopefully this helps.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. I've just tried from fresh and it works as expected. Thanks